# Trying to create a Visit Counter on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, azure

I have the HTML code and all the post and get functions going to my COSMOS (NoSql) DB all work correctly. So whenever I refresh the page, cosmos updates the visit counter by one.

But I cant seem to figure out a way to have that count displayed on the html. Spent legit 8 hours spinning wheels. Any insight/help would be appreciated.

```
<!-- JavaScript code in your website to trigger the function for recording visits and fetch visit count -->
<script>
  // Function to record a visit
  function recordVisit() {
    fetch('the target website', {
      method: 'POST',
      // Additional options if needed
    });
  }

  // Function to fetch and display visit count
  function getVisitCount() {
    fetch('the target website')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        // Constant for HTML content
        const visitCountHTML = `<div>Current Visitors: ${data.visitCount}</div>`;
        
        // Display the current visit count on your website
        document.getElementById('visitCount').innerHTML = visitCountHTML;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching or processing data:', error);
      });
  }

  // Call the functions to record a visit and fetch visit count after the DOM is fully loaded
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    recordVisit();
    getVisitCount();
  });
</script>

<!-- HTML element to display the visit count -->
visits: <div id="VisitCount"></div>
```

Comment: What happens with your current code?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, all my functions and calls work but I just cant get the visitCount to display.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes just two warnings it looks like:                                                                                                                                                                       " Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ambient-light-sensor'.
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'battery'. "

Comment: I was looking at the console in the wrong page, after using the console and chatgpt I was able to ID that the API I was parsing was not JSON, it was plain text. It works now, thank you so much for pointing me in the right diretcion

Comment: If you found a working solution, feel free to add it as an answer to your question, so others with similar issues benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Cosmos DB supports data which is only in Json format it is needed to parse with Json instead of plain text and below is the code which displays the views count on HTML page and also update in cosmos container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Visit Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Visit Counter</h1>
    <p>Refresh this page to increase the visit count!</p>
    <h2 id="visitCount">Current Visitors: Loading...</h2>

    <script>
        function getVisitCount() {
            fetch('/visitcount')
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    const visitCountHTML = `<div>Current Visitors: ${data.visitCount}</div>`;
                                     document.getElementById('visitCount').innerHTML = visitCountHTML;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching or processing data:', error);
                });
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            getVisitCount(); 
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server Side Code:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const { CosmosClient } = require('@azure/cosmos');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({ 
    endpoint: '*****',
    key: '*****'
});
const databaseId = 'newDb';
const containerId = 'newCont';

async function updateVisitCounter() {
    try {
        const { database } = await cosmosClient.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: databaseId });
        const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: containerId });

        const { resources: items } = await container.items.readAll().fetchAll();
        const currentItem = items[0]; 

        currentItem.visitCount += 1; 

        await container.item(currentItem.id).replace(currentItem);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating visit counter in Cosmos DB:', error);
    }
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    updateVisitCounter(); 
    next();
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/visitcount', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { database } = await cosmosClient.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: databaseId });
        const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: containerId });

        const { resources: items } = await container.items.readAll().fetchAll();
        const currentItem = items[0]; 

        res.json({ visitCount: currentItem.visitCount });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching visit count from Cosmos DB:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**Output on server:**
[image]

**Updated output in Cosmos DB:**

```js
{
    "id": "unique_id_1",
    "visitorIP": "192.168.1.1",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-04T12:30:45Z",
    "pageVisited": "/home",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.12345.67 Safari/537.36",
    "visitCount": 11
}
```

Refer this [link](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/blob/main/features.md) for permission policy errors.